# Entity Framework with Instead Of triggers

Tags: c#, entity-framework, triggers

I am using EF with a SQL Server database. I created a view and an `Instead Of Insert` trigger for that view which looks like this:

```
insert into Target (value, someFk) 
select value, 4 from inserted
select id from Target where @@ROWCOUNT > 0 and id = scope_identity()
```

I mapped the view into an EF edmx. When I try to add an entity I get the following exception when I call `SaveChanges()`:

> *Unable to update the EntitySet 'TargetView' because it has a DefiningQuery and no  element exists in the
>    element to support the current
>   operation.*

The view has an identity column marked in the mapping.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you open EDMX file with an xml editor, in the section where TargetView is defined you will have some xml similar to the following;

```
<EntitySet Name=".."  
           EntityType=".." 
           store:Type="Views" 
           store:Schema=".." 
           store:Name="..">
<DefiningQuery>SELECT ....</DefiningQuery>
```

You need to change this xml section in order to have CRUD operations;

```
<EntitySet Name=".."  
           EntityType=".."  
           store:Type="Tables" 
           Schema=".." />
```

Comment: +1 see also this link http://smehrozalam.wordpress.com/2009/08/12/entity-framework-creating-a-model-using-views-instead-of-tables/

Comment: @nonnb great article which describes alternative methods; thanks for sharing.

Comment: This works, but this is awfully wrong. Hope EF 5.0 will add some improvement here.

Comment: @Jaster I do agree with you; EF is a headache when compared with other ORM tools like nhibernate.

Comment: nhibernate is not any better. For this issue it seems to do a better job. Compared to EF it has other limitations (auto generation/mapping, performance, etc). To be honest I do not like any OR mapper when it comes to serious database operations.