# Entity Framework, view and instead of insert trigger. Can't insert a row into the view

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, t-sql, view, triggers

I can't insert an entity into the mapped view.
The error I get is:

> Store, insert or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0)

I know how to use stored procedures, but it is more interesting for me to try a solution with an instead of trigger on insert row view event. I don't get any error when I delete, update or insert in t-sql code, but I can't INSERT a row using EF. Update and delete work in EF, but INSERT doesn't.

Code:

```sql
create view TestInsert
as
    select a.table_id, a.name
    from TableA as a

create trigger tr_works_via_tsql_but_not_ef_for_some_reason
on TestInsert
instead of isert
begin
   insert into TableA (table_id, name)
   select table_id, name from inserted;
end
```

```csharp
[Table(TestInsert)]
public class TestInsert
{
   [Key]
   public int table_id { get; set; }
   public string name { get; set; }
}
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: This is a similar question (but I don't have edmx file):  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12217169/entity-framework-with-instead-of-triggers

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Hooray, I have found the solution!
The body of instead of trigger **must return an id for the table**.

```
create trigger tr_works_via_tsql_but_not_ef_for_some_reason
on TestInsert
instead of isert
begin
   insert into TableA (table_id, name)
   select table_id, name from inserted;

   **select id from TableA where @@ROWCOUNT > 0 and id = scope_identity()**
end
```

I use direct mapping and there is no edmx file in my project.
This is the source of the answer:
[Entity Framework with Instead Of triggers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12217169/entity-framework-with-instead-of-triggers)

Comment: Thank you for this, I've spent several hours trying to fix it. I couldn't use cascade delete because of the possible cycles, because of that I used instead of delete trigger. But also I had to use merge statement, and it required to add instead of insert and update triggers as well, after what EF create failed.